# How to redeploy network?

Tags: hyperledger-composer

I have a network version where I fixed a small bug in the .js file and added a function. I would like to redeploy the network (on the same version).

I stop/teardown Fabric and restart it. Delete the card and .bna file, then re-create the card and .bna file. After that I install and start the network. Last step is to start the REST server.

Even after all these steps, the REST server does not list my new function, indicating it has not been updated?

Do I have to change the version number if I modify the script.js and model.cto files?

Comment: if you continue using the above approach rather than using composer network upgrade then you will probably have to delete the dev-* docker images as well otherwise fabric may not rebuild the chaincode image and you get the issue you are seeing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As david_k points out in 'comments' above - you should use `composer network upgrade` to upgrade the business network (no need to 'teardown' your Fabric environment) as well as stop the REST server as you've done. See https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/reference/composer.network.upgrade.html and example of it in use in the tutorials https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/tutorials/queries . Once you've upgraded your business network successfully, and pinged it successfully, you can stop/remove the old dev-* business network containers as indicated. You would then start the REST server again, use the same business network card (eg. an admin card) when prompted / as a parameter to the start command. Then in a new browser session, you can test your REST APIs (or as suits). If you're not seeing the new function (or it errors), you should check your decorators/naming in your logic.js file to see the right transaction function is being called for a named transaction.